# porque no redirecciona el formulario php en remoto

Tags: php

Soy un novato total en programación y en esta web. 
Estoy trabajando una pag con php con contraseña para acceso a otra pag. dentro del sitio, al hacer las pruebas En Localhost funcona bien, pero cuando trabajo con mi servidor no me redirecciona a ninguna pág el codigo completo es:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Linkar 1</title>
 <style>
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  #caja0 {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   background: #E0E0E0;
   width: 95%;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   padding: 1%;
   padding-bottom: 2%;
   margin: 1% auto;
  }

  h3 {font-size: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
  }

  hr {
   border: solid 2px red;
   margin: 1em;
  }

  .rojo {
color: #FF0004;
 font-weight: bold;
  }
  #verde{color: #09FF00;}
  h1{
        text-align:center;
    }

    table{
        background-color:#FFC;
        padding:25px;
        border:#666 5px solid;
    }

    .no_validado{
        font-size:18px;
        color:#F00;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .validado{
        font-size:18px;
        color:#0C3;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="caja0">

  <h3>Linkar a otros sitios con contraseña</h3>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
 <table width="48%" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td>Pon contraseña:</td>
   <td><label for="nombre_usuario"></label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre_usuario" id="nombre_usuario">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="enviando" id="enviando" value="Enviar">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
  <?php
  /*Este código comprueba el envío del formulario*/
  if(isset($_POST["enviando"])){
   /*$_POST es una var Super Global y son Arrays y eso es lo que estamos haciendo con este formulario*/
   /*Con estas var almacenamos lo que el usuario ha introducido en los cuadros de texto en caso de que pulse el botón de Enviar  */
   $usuario=$_POST["nombre_usuario"];


   if($usuario=="Juan"){

   //echo(" Puedes entrar ya");
   /*Codigo para redirrecionar a otra pág dentro el sitio*/
   header('Location: /Probando.html');
   /*Codigo para redirrecionar a otra WEB*/
    //header('Location:http://jpbenavente.com/index.html');

   }else{ echo("No puedes entrar nunca");


        }//Del 2º if

   };//DEL iF 
  ?>

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Hola @Jesús cual que error te saca ? creeria que es por las ruta, siempre procura usar rutas relativas

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. También es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Aqui te dejo una guía de cómo deberían ser los ejemplos: [mínimos, completos y verificables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Si estas enviando el formulario a la misma pagina donde estas el action lo puedes omitir.

Comment: Intenta el header con header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $location); donde location deberia ser '/Probando.html' asumiendo que ese archivo este dentro de tu directorio donde mismo tienes almacenado la pagina de login

Comment: en teoria, lo mejor que puede hacer es tener 3 archivos; 1) el del formulario donde el usuario introduce los datos, 2) el archivo controlador.php (por ejemplo) en el que validas que la informacion suministrada sea eficiente  dependeidndo de ahi si es veras redireccionas a el 3) archivo y si no al anterior

Comment: de hecho el este `header` si funciona, lo probe en mis archivos y me lelva a tu servidor bro, asi que la logica es la que te esta fallando [tu servidor][1]


  [1]: http://header('Location:http://jpbenavente.com/index.html');

Comment: Te muestra algun error? viste los logs? tu servidor puede ejecutar php? probé tu código y funciona bien

Comment: que versión de php tienes? (http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente el problema es que estás llamando a header pero antes de eso ya estás devolviendo la respuesta a la petición.

Es decir, esto sería incorrecto

```
<html>
<?php
header();
?>
```

Mientras que esto funcionaría, ya que haces el redirect antes de responder a la petición.

```
<?php
header();
?>
<html>
```

Prueba cambiando tu página, moviendo la parte de php que comprueba el usuario al principio. También, es buena práctica poner un `die` o exit después del header. Hay algunos scrappers que podrían ignorar el redirect y seguiría la petición (con potenciales efectos no deseables)

El código quedaría más o menos así:

```
<?php
/*Este código comprueba el envío del formulario*/
if(isset($_POST["enviando"])){
/*$_POST es una var Super Global y son Arrays y eso es lo que estamos haciendo con este formulario*/
/*Con estas var almacenamos lo que el usuario ha introducido en los cuadros de texto en caso de que pulse el botón de Enviar  */
$usuario=$_POST["nombre_usuario"];


if($usuario=="Juan"){

//echo(" Puedes entrar ya");
/*Codigo para redirrecionar a otra pág dentro el sitio*/
header('Location: /Probando.html');
die("You shall not pass!!"); // Es trabajo del navegador hacer el redirect. Abortamos si no lo hace
/*Codigo para redirrecionar a otra WEB*/
//header('Location:http://jpbenavente.com/index.html');

}else{ echo("No puedes entrar nunca");


    }//Del 2º if

};//DEL iF 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Linkar 1</title>
 <style>
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  #caja0 {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   background: #E0E0E0;
   width: 95%;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   padding: 1%;
   padding-bottom: 2%;
   margin: 1% auto;
  }

  h3 {font-size: 1.5em;
   text-align: center;
  }

  hr {
   border: solid 2px red;
   margin: 1em;
  }

  .rojo {
color: #FF0004;
 font-weight: bold;
  }
  #verde{color: #09FF00;}
  h1{
        text-align:center;
    }

    table{
        background-color:#FFC;
        padding:25px;
        border:#666 5px solid;
    }

    .no_validado{
        font-size:18px;
        color:#F00;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .validado{
        font-size:18px;
        color:#0C3;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="caja0">

  <h3>Linkar a otros sitios con contraseña</h3>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
 <table width="48%" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td>Pon contraseña:</td>
   <td><label for="nombre_usuario"></label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre_usuario" id="nombre_usuario">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="enviando" id="enviando" value="Enviar">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias sois la bomba. Os agradezco vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias sois la bomba. Os agradezco vuestra ayuda. Parece ser que había cometido 2 errores justo como habíais dicho: no colocar el código al principio y omitir la instrucción die("You shall not pass!!");